# Showing if two events determined by a die toss are independent or not.

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

I'm having trouble setting up a problem with random variables to determine if two events A and B are independent or not. The problem is as follows:

*A fair die is repeatedly toss until the first even number apears. The random variable $X$ is defined as the number of toss in which the first even number appears. Define the following events: $A:=X$ is even. $B:=X$ is a multiple of 3.
Determine if A and B are independent.*

This is my approach:

We know that two events A and B are independent iff $\,\mathbb{P}(A\cap{B})=\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)$. I will find the probability of A, B and their intersection and then show they are not equal. Hence, proving that A and B are not independent.

Define $\Omega:=\{(E),(O,E),(O,O,E),(O,O,O,E),...\}$. Each $\omega$ in $\Omega$ is the event in which $n$ die tosses are required to get an even number. Now, our random variable $X$ can be defined as:

$$X(\omega)=|\omega|$$

The number of elements in each $\omega$, i.e., the number of die tosses. Now, we can compute the probability of A, B and $A\cap{B}$ as follows:

$$\mathbb{P}(A)=\mathbb{P}(X=2n)\,n\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$$

Which we can write as:

$$\mathbb{P}(\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)=2n\})=\mathbb{P}\{(O,E),(O,O,O,E),(O,O,O,O,O,E),...\}$$

Since these events are disjoint, we can put the probability as:

$$\mathbb{P}(\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)=2n\})=\mathbb{P}\{(O,E)\}+\mathbb{P}\{(O,O,O,E)\}+\mathbb{P}\{(O,O,O,O,O,E)\}+...$$

The probability of obtaining an even or an odd face in the die is $\frac{1}{2}$. Since each toss is independent and the die is fair, each case can be seen as:

$$\mathbb{P}\{(O,E)\}+\mathbb{P}\{(O,O,O,E)\}+\mathbb{P}\{(O,O,O,O,O,E)\}+...=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{4}+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{6}+...=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}^{2n}$$

Which can be simplified to:

$$\mathbb{P}(A)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}^{n}=\frac{1}{3}$$

By a similar procedure it can be shown that:

$$\mathbb{P}(B)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}^{3n}=\frac{1}{7}$$

And:

$$\mathbb{P}(A\cap{B})=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}^{6n}=\frac{1}{63}$$

Which shows that $\mathbb{P}(A\cap{B})\neq\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)$

Then, the events are not independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm having trouble setting up a problem with random variables to determine if two events A and B are independent or not.

No you are not.  You have done it.

You have basically shown that $X$ is a geometrically distributed random variable with success-rate parameter $1/2$, so:  $$\mathsf P(X{=}n)=2^{-n}\,\mathbf 1_{n\in\Bbb N^+}$$

Then you have evaluated the probability of $X$ being divisible by a natural-number using the closed form of the geometric series.
$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X\in\{kn:n\in\Bbb N^+\}) &=\mathsf P(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{X{=}kn\})\\[1ex]&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (2^{-k})^n&(\text{provided }k\in\Bbb N^+)\\[2ex]&=\dfrac{1}{2^k-1}\\[3ex]\mathsf P(A)&=\dfrac{1}{2^2-1}\\\mathsf P(B)&=\dfrac 1{2^3-1}\\\mathsf P(A\cap B)&=\dfrac{1}{2^6-1}\end{align}$$

Thus proving that the events, $A$ and $B$, are not independent.